# how to Pass start pointer of linked list as pointer in C++

Tags: c++

In C++ programming I was observing how pointers are passed in linked list implementation

here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node {
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node(int x) {
        data = x;
        next = NULL;
    }

};

void traverse(Node *root) {
    Node *ptr = root;
    while(ptr != NULL) {
        cout<<ptr->data;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
}

void alter(Node* root) {
    root->next = NULL;
}

void insert(Node* root) {
    Node *ptr = new Node(10);
    ptr->next = root;
    root = ptr;
}

int main(void) {
    Node *start = new Node(3);
    start->next = new Node(4);
    start->next->next = new Node(5);
    traverse(start);  // prints 3 4 5
    alter(start); 
    traverse(start);  // prints 3  here list is altered
    insert(start);
    traverse(start);  // print 3  here 10 is not added as a node
}
```

the confusion i have is when i passed "start" as a parameter in "alter" in function call (inside main()) it altered my linked list but when i passed "start" as a parameter in "insert" in function call (inside main()), it doesn't change where my root is pointing to inside the function definition to where "start" inside the "main" function (in short the node is not inserted).

Please tell me where i am getting this wrong. any help is appreciated

PS : i know how to pass it using reference i.e

```
//function definition
void insert(Node*& root) {
        Node *ptr = new Node(10);
        ptr->next = root;
        root = ptr;
    }

// function call
insert(start);
```

I want to know what is going wrong in first code snippet. i tried very hard to explain my doubt.
please help!

Comment: There is a reason why you pass by reference vs. by value. Very important reason. The different syntax is not just cosmetic, and the results are completely different. The whole reason for passing by reference is that, otherwise, when passing by value, the function parameter is a copy of the original value being passed to it, so modifying it does absolutely nothing to the original value, unlike when passing it by reference. Can you clarify which part of this, exactly, is unclear to you?

Comment: I am having problem that when I passed start in alter(start) (function call inside main()) and did root->next=NULL(inside alter definition) my linked list end up having one element but when I passed start in a same way in insert new node was not inserted ,both the function calling method was same for alter function and for insert function but one changed original linked list and other does not.

Comment: Again, that's the difference between passing by reference vs. by value. Modifying a function parameter that's passed by reference modifies the original value that gets in. Modifying a function parameter that's passed by value does not modify the original value. Which part of that is unclear to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To emphesis perrel answer you could do it like this:

```
void insert(Node** root) {
    Node *ptr = new Node(10);
    ptr->next = *root;
    *root = ptr;
}

int main(void) {
    Node *start = new Node(3);
    start->next = new Node(4);
    start->next->next = new Node(5);
    traverse(start);  // prints 3 4 5
    alter(start); 
    traverse(start);  // prints 3  here list is altered
    insert(&start);
    traverse(start);  // print 3  here 10 is not added as a node

}
```

although I agreed that perrel Insert is more readable and preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
void f(int i) {
  i = i + 10;
}

....
int j = 5;
f(j);
// what is the value if j here?
```

At this point the value of j is still 5. To actually change the value of j, you need to (a) pass a pointer, or (b) return a value:

```
// (a)
void f_a(int* i) {
  *i = *i + 10;
}

// (b)
int f_b(int i) {
  return i + 10;
}

....
int j = 5;
// (a)
f_a(&j);
// here j is 15.

// (b)
j = f_b(j);
// here j is 25.
```

I personally think (b) is the better option.

```
Node* insert(Node* root) {
  Node *ptr = new Node(10);
  ptr->next = root;
  return ptr;
}

....
root = insert(root);
```

Note that in this example type of `i` is an `int` so for option (a) we need to pass a pointer to `int` (type of `i`). In your case the of `root` is `Node *` so you need to pass a `Node **`, i.e., a pointer to type of `root`.

Comment: Or you can take by reference.

Comment: Sure, but with refs the intention is not clear at the call site.

Comment: Sure, but you've said `To actually change the value of j, you need to (a) pass a pointer, or (b) return a value`.